# How to avoid auto-disable Low Power Mode on iOS9 when charging

Tags: iphone, ios

In iOS9, when Low Power Mode is activated, and you are charging your iPhone, when charge percentage gets to 80%, the iPhone disables Low Power Mode automatically.

Is there any way to avoid this automatic change and let Low Power Mode remain activated?

Comment: While I'm short on testing it, you can manually switch the low power mode in "Settings" > "Battery". It's worth a shot trying to manually enable it to see if it keeps it enabled then. Many times a suggested or automatic feature can be made permanent by manually changing its state.

Comment: I am not asking to do it manually, I am asking to do it automatically.

Comment: What I meant to say here was that some options, which had been toggled once manually may retain the setting afterwards.

Comment: Is not working. You have to turn manually the switch everytime you charge your phone.

Comment: Ok. Fair enough. As I initially stated, I was short on testing it here, so just a suggestion from other functions I've seen working like that. Back to the drawing board then.

Answer (score 2):

Just tested this - you can get Siri to turn low power on which saves navigating to the Battery settings screen. Just ask Siri to "Turn on low power mode"

Answer (score 1):

While there is no direct setting for this, you can [set up an automation](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/shortcuts/apdfbdbd7123/ios) in the Shortcuts app of your iPhone.

To achieve this, go to the "Automation" tab in the Shortcuts app and tap "Create Personal Automation" or the "+" button (if you already have any automations). Then, select the "Battery Level" parameter, glide the slider to 80%, and choose "Rises above 80%".

Click "Next", search for "Set Low Power Mode" (in the search bar) and click on the action to add it. Make sure the parameter is set like this: "`Turn` Low Power Mode `On`". Tap "Next".

Then, you can toggle off the "Ask before running" option (unless you prefer to be prompted to run the shortcut each time), and the "Notify when run" option (just to avoid you getting a notification each time). And tap "Done".

Even though Low Power Mode will be turned off whenever your battery rises above 80% (or reaches 80%), this automation will immediately turn Low Power mode on again.

[image: Screenshot taken on iPhone of the Shortcuts app while setting up the 'When' in an automation (When battery rises above 80%)] [image: Screenshot taken on iPhone of the Shortcuts app when the 'Turn Low Power Mode On' action is added] [image: Screenshot taken on iPhone of the Shortcuts app with the automation's 'summary' with 'Ask Before Running' and 'Notify When Run' disabled]

<sup>Click images to open full size</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Low Power mode can be manually toggled on and off under the Settings App >> Battery >> Low Power.  This has been available on [iOS 11 and later](https://www.howtogeek.com/229224/how-to-use-low-power-mode-on-an-iphone-and-what-exactly-it-does/).

This can also be triggered with Siri by saying something to the effect of “Hey Siri, turn [on|off] Low Power Mode.”

[image: Battery Settings, Low Power Mode Switch]